# what can cause memory leak (or constant increase)? shared memory DLL + c# app

Tags: c#, c++, c

I have simple shared memory DLL for interprocess data exchange from unmanaged to managed app.
And I noticed that my managed app memory is growing in size steadily.
Can someone advise what can be the cause, how to find it and how to fix it?
Relevant parts of codes below.

cpp SharedMem.DLL:

```
#pragma data_seg( ".IPC" )
....
double darr[MAXITEMS] = { 0.0 } ; 
....
#pragma data_seg()
....
double __stdcall MGetDouble (int idx)
{
    if ( idx>= 0 && idx < MAXITEMS)
    {
        return darr[idx]; 
    }
    else
    {
        return -1.0 ; 
    }
}

int __stdcall MSetDouble (int idx, double dvalue)
{
    if ( idx>= 0 && idx< MAXITEMS)
    {
        darr[idx] = dvalue;
        return idx;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

and c# app:

```
[DllImport("SharedMem.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern double MGetDouble(int index);

....

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(dosmth);
}

public object lockobj = new object();

public void dosmth(object o)
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockobj, 50))
    {
        ....
        double[,] matrix = new double[size, TSIZE];
        ....
        double gvd;
        int k;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < TSIZE; j++) 
            {
                k++; //k can be up to 2k-4k typically
                gvd = MGetDouble(k);
                matrix[i, j] = gvd;
            }
            //... do the stuff
         Monitor.Exit(lockobj);        
     }

}
```

Comment: how much does it grow? does it stop at some point?

Comment: Have you tried taking hang dumps to see what things are causing the increase in memory usage?

Comment: Grows about 20m per hour. I noticed it when got OutOfmemory exception and when app got to about 800m in size (windows 7 64bit with 4GB memory). When MGetDouble() is not used it doesn't grow.

Comment: I tried debugging with windbg and sos.dll, but, as I'm not well experienced in this area, couldn't find out anything. Can you point me to some good articles about dealing with such kinds of problems?

Comment: What's the period of timer1 compared to the time taken to execute dosmth()? Is ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads steadily decreasing? You should also only be calling Monitor.Exit when TryEnter succeeds.

Comment: You should try and localize the cause for a leak. May be just try the scheduling without actually calling MGetDouble(...)

Comment: timer1 runs every 250 ms and dosmth() usually takes much less time, tough I have to trace it's timing now.

Comment: dosmth() takes 20-25ms on average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this aproach:

```
public class doSmthClass()
{
    public void doSmthfromClass(...
}
```

and alter your "outer" do smth:

```
public void dosmth(object o)
{
  :
  var myInstance = new doSmthClass();
  myInstance.doSmthFromClass();
  :
}
```

Comment: in real code it's somewhat similar (I simplified the code for question), except that myInstance remains alive all the time and I can't change this.

Comment: if myInstance remains alive and never being disposed your problem is within the unmanged area of your code which is not being correctly disposed.

Comment: looks like that, as without calling MgetDouble() and by filling matrix[,] with random data there's no growth. but how? the memory (darr) is allocated in DLL once and remains unchanged, dosmth() is reading practically the same indexes from MgetDouble(). why would garbage collector not free the memory for local var matrix[,] ? i guess need to spend more time with windbg/sos

Comment: and I'll think how to redesign and apply your suggestion, thx

Comment: try to to link to a managed dll which do nothing - see if you get the same behavior in terms of memory. I mean to offer that you change focus from finding the line to a more global view on the linked dll - just to be sure the problem is not in the linking itself. if you get somewhat the same problem - your problem is related to how .NET link dll's if not - it's the unmanaged code.

Comment: I redesigned, like you suggested (with myInstance) and looks like now it's ok, grown to about 110m and remains stable around that number for the last 2 hours. So it must be something related to GC, I guess. If I'll get OutOfMemory exception again, I'll save the memory dump and try to check it. Thanks you all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

QueueUserWorkItem will run your method on the Thread Pool(TP) - if previous request haven't finished yet the new request would block a TP thread. After some time if the TP runs low on free threads it will start creating more threads which consume at least 1MB of stack each.

If it makes sense for your application you may want to run the new requests after the previous have finished(for example - run the timer so that it executes once and use Timer.Change to schedule the next execution time when you finish with the processing).

You could also use [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) with the [SOS extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) and inspect your roots with commands like DumpHeap/HeapStat to see where exactly your memory goes.

Comment: I did try without threadpool, just calling dosmth(), and the problem remained.

Comment: I also spent some time with windbg/sos and couldn't find what grows. Biggest size had System.String and System.Double[,] (matrix[,] in my code), but they were not growing steadily.

Comment: @NickBilak - the problem will exist even if you don't call the thread pool directly - your timer callback gets executed on a TP worker thread. Executions may still overlap(one can start before the previous one having finished).

Comment: I've read that Windows.Forms.Timer is executing on the main UI thread, not TP. Is this wrong? Also I tried with System.Timers.Timer (mTimer.Enabled = false; .. do smth .. mTimer.Enabled = true;) thus ensuring that only one instance is running. Besides there is a lock for the same purpose.

Comment: I didn't know it was winforms app. Then you don't need the synchronization(lock) at all. In this case your UI thread's queue may get clotted with requests if it cannot process them with the speed the timer kicks in periodically. I doubt those requests may cause such a drastic memory leaks though(which still depends on the frequency of the timer).

Comment: I think now I have to trace the timing of dosmth(), maybe sometimes it takes longer than usually. You might hit the point, thx.

Comment: No, it's actually a method of another class instance and running on separate thread and I need the lock. What I said (about winforms) is I was checking with forms.timer without TP and it still grows. And UI is not freezing, so the queue must be ok.